# does the use of meta model can cause memory leak in hibernate code?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, metamodel

Analyzing heap dump of tomcat app that based `hibernate 4.3.1.final` + `Spring 4' 
shows that there is a leak on

`org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl` it seems related to with `MetaModel` (**maybe** meta model with `@embeddedId`)

Does any one have experience that ?

Thanks ,

Alon

some info from dump :

**Class Name | Shallow Heap| Retained Heap**

```
 org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl @ 0x7839de890
 136 8,109,256 
 \factory org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory$TypeScopeImpl @ 0x7839de880
  16 16 
  .\typeScope org.hibernate.type.ComponentType @ 0x783d8c760
  56 616 
 ..\hibernateType org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.EmbeddableTypeImpl @ 0x783d8c3f8
 48 1,216 
 ...\attributeType org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.SingularAttributeImpl$Identifier        @ 0x783d8c338
 40 40 
 ....\id class org.jpp.domain.security.ProjectPermission_ @ 0x784134cf8
 8 8 
 .....\[3985] java.lang.Object[10240] @ 0x784ecd118
 40,976 1,087,264 
 ......\elementData java.util.Vector @ 0x7832e2680
 32 1,087,296 
 .......\classes org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @ 0x7832c76c0
 184 1,454,824 
 ........+<classloader> class com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread @      0x783bbda40
```

Comment: Yes, I'm experiencing cursor leaks w/ Spring 4 and Hibernate 4.3.1.  This is from a project that was on Spring 3.2 and Hibernate 3.6 which wasn't leaking cursors at the time.

Comment: any luck with preventing it?

Comment: It ended up being not Hibernate related.  The Stored Procedure I was calling was opening cursors and not closing them.